# AddEventlistner for navbar is not working for long time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I was trying to convert html+css+javascript [Project][1] into React js , I tried  adding addEventListener by UseEffect ([blog for addEventListener][2]) but it is working for very short period of time for navbar onclicking nav button in mobile `enter code here`phone view and also it showing only in rendering after completing rending it doesn't show any Effect.

**My [code][3]** .

[1]: https://codepen .io/WebDevSimplified/ pen/LqKQRK
[2]: [How to add event listener in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61085006/how-to-add-event-listener-in-react)
[3]: https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-22dzx

Answer (score 1):

Its small mistake, convert `a` tag to `div` tag and it will solve your problem

```
<a  href="./" class="toggle-button">
```

TO

```
<div className="toggle-button">
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-forked-lj04p?file=/src/Navbar.js