# How can and where should I add an onKeyDown event Listener for my "Save Employee" button in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, keyboard-events, onkeydown, codesandbox

[image: screen capture]
[CodeSandbox Repo](https://codesandbox.io/s/state-practice-vs9k73?file=/src/SaveEmployee.js)

I would like to listen to `keyDown` events, specifically, the key <kbd>S</kbd> so users can easily save a randomly generated employee conveniently instead of clicking the `Save Employee` button multiple times.

In JavaScript, I would add the event on the document body like, `document.body.addEventListener('keydown')`, but in React I don't know where to place the event. For now, I added it inside the `index.js` file like:
`onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}`

I commented out my failed attempt (check image, code repo, or snippet below).

```
function SaveEmployee({ ...props }) {
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);

  const displayEmployee = () => {
    setEmployees((current) => [...current, { ...props }]);
  };


  // const displayEmployee = (event) => {
  //   if (event.key === "KeyS") { setEmployees((current) => [...current, { ...props }]);
  //   } else  { console.log('do nothing');    }
  // };

return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button title="Save new random employee data" onClick={displayEmployee}>
          Save Employee
        </button>
      </div>
      ...
```

1. The keyCode property is deprecated so I tried the event.key but no luck yet.
2. I also tried creating a separate component `KeyDownEvents.js` to see if splitting the code from `SaveEmployee.js` would fix the issue and to see if it works like `document.body.addEventListener`, since `Index.js` is the main component that houses all children components, but no luck.
   [image: KeyDownEvents.js file and Index.js]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add event listener in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61085006/how-to-add-event-listener-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

- There is problem with the event name , on the code sand box you are listening to an event named onClick which is wrong .

`onCLick`: There no event named like this . ( true you can handle events on the react element with `onClick={someFunction}` , but events with using `element.addEventListener(event)` are not named like that )

`click`: Mouse click event .

`keydown`: Keyboard click down event .

- Solution would be

```
  /*  useEffect  */

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "s") {
      console.log("yay s");
    }
    if (event.key === "S") {
      console.log("yay capital s");
    }
  }; // You might also want to move this function outside useEffect

  useEffect((props) => {
    // before ==> window.addEventListener("onClick", handleClick);
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleClick);
  }, []);
```

- Modified code sandbox with the solution
  https://codesandbox.io/s/state-practice-forked-9m7z7j?file=/src/SaveEmployee.js

Comment: This is correct if you are wanting to implement anywhere on page, but you should remove the eventListener on component unmount `useEffect(() => {...; return (() => {window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleClick); }) }, [])`

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` is for handling mouse events. You want to use `onKeyPress` (or `onKeyUp` or `onKeyDown`. Read [Q/A: onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)).

The `event.key` for `"S"` is not `"KeyS"`, it is simply `"s"` (or `"S"` if you want it to be `shift`+`s`)

```js
export default function SaveEmployee(props) {
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);

  const displayEmployee = () => {
    console.log('mouse click');
    setEmployees((current) => [...current, { ...props }]);
  };

  const displayEmployeeKeyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "s") {
      console.log("key click");
      setEmployees((current) => [...current, { ...props }]);
    } else {
      console.log("do nothing");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button
          title="Save new random employee data"
          onClick={displayEmployee}
          onKeyPress={displayEmployeeKeyPress}
        >
          Save Employee
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

NOTE: that this event only fires if you have the `<button>` in focus.

[View on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-franklin-ckmf2f?file=/src/SaveEmployee.jsx)

Comment: This solution means that you need to focus on the button and then click s , I believe the OP needed the keyboard click when the user is anywhere not just when focusing on the save button .

Comment: Yes. I want the keyboard click anywhere on the screen so when a user press keys like "S" they would be able to Save the data, if they press another key like "D" they'll be able to delete Data and so forth. I want to put all of these events together inside a parent component called "HandleClick.js" but the issue is I dont know how to trigger the keyboard events with useEffect render which is housed inside `SaveEmployee.js`. [Here's the latest codesandbox:] (https://codesandbox.io/s/state-practice-vs9k73?file=/src/SaveEmployee.js:111-123)